# Multi inline edit?

Tags: reporting, list-view

I swear I saw this once - but wasn't there a feature where you could inline edit multiple cells in a list view and/or report all with one click? So - e.g. updating the opportunity stage to `Closed Won` for 20 records at once?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind - I found it. In the list view just tick the boxes on the left for the records you want to update. Update one cell and in the popup select "Update X selected items". I still don't know if the same is possible in reports though.